# Softlayer HAProxy with failover

Tags: haproxy, failover, keepalived

I have 2 virtual servers on Softlayer, both running HAProxy. I am trying to set up failover with keepalived. Each server has a private IP and public IP, and they are on the same VLAN. I've tried many different settings for keepalived, but stopping HAProxy on master, it does not failover to the BACKUP.

I read that multicast was not supported, so I have since changed my settings to unicast. The settings now, on backup/master are basically this:

```
vrrp_script chk_haproxy {
  script "pidof haproxy"
  interval 2
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
  debug 2
  interface eth1
  state MASTER
  virtual_router_id 51
  priority 101
  unicast_src_ip 1.2.3.4        # My IP
  unicast_peer {
    5.6.7.8                   # peer IP
  }
  track_script {
    chk_haproxy
  }
}
```

Where MYIP is the public IP address of the server the conf file is on, and PEERIP is the public IP address of the peer. Still it is not working. Stopping HAProxy on the master, it does not failover to the backup.

I am wondering if anyone has set up HAProxy with failover on Softlayer, and how they went about accomplishing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to get this set up, and here's how I did it:

1. I created a global IP address using SoftLayer's control panel.
2. I have Debian 7 on both HAProxy virtual servers. I added the global IP address to eth1 interface on both servers.
3. Here's the HAProxy settings used on both servers:

   ```
   global
     log 127.0.0.1 local0
     log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
     maxconn 4096
     user haproxy
     group haproxy

   defaults
     log global  
     mode http    
     option httplog 
     option dontlognull
     retries 3
     maxconn 2000
     option redispatch
     timeout connect 5000
     timeout client 50000
     timeout server 50000
     stats uri / haproxy

   listen webfarm 0.0.0.0:80
     mode http
     stats enable
     stats uri /haproxy?stats
     stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
     stats auth haproxy:stats
     balance roundrobin
     cookie LBN insert indirect nocache
     option httpclose
     option forwardfor
     server app1-west <public_ip>:8080 cookie node1 check
     server app2-west <public_ip>:8080 cookie node2 check
   ```
4. Here's the Keepalived settings on MASTER server:

   ```
   global_defs {
       notification_email {
           admin@mydomain.com
       }
       notification_email_from me@me.com
       smtp_server 127.0.0.1
       smtp_connect_timeout 30
       router_id LB_MASTER_ACTIVE
   }

   # Define the script used to check if haproxy is still working
   vrrp_script chk_haproxy {
       script "killall -0 haproxy"   # verify the pid existance
       interval 2                    # check every 2 seconds
       weight 2                      # add 2 points of prio if OK
   }

   # Virtual interface.
   vrrp_instance VI_1 {
       state MASTER
       interface eth1
       virtual_router_id 51
       priority 101
       smtp_alert 

       authentication {
           auth_type PASS
           auth_pass 1111 #replace with random string
       }

       vrrp_unicast_bind <my_private_ip>
       vrrp_unicast_peer <peers_private_ip>

       # Check if HAProxy is running or not.
       track_script {
           chk_haproxy
       }
       notify_master /usr/bin/reroute_global
   }
   ```
5. Here's the Keepalived settings on BACKUP server:

   ```
   global_defs {
       notification_email {
           admin@mydomain.com
       }
       notification_email_from me@me.com
       smtp_server 127.0.0.1
       smtp_connect_timeout 30
       router_id LB_BACKUP_PASSIVE
   }

   # Define the script used to check if haproxy is still working
   vrrp_script chk_haproxy {
       script "killall -0 haproxy"   # verify the pid existance
       interval 2                    # check every 2 seconds
       weight 2                      # add 2 points of prio if OK
   }

   # Virtual interface.
   vrrp_instance VI_1 {
       state BACKUP
       interface eth1
       virtual_router_id 51
       priority 100
       smtp_alert 
       advert_int 1

       authentication {
           auth_type PASS
           auth_pass 1111 #replace with random string
       }

       vrrp_unicast_bind <my_private_ip>
       vrrp_unicast_peer <peers_private_ip>

       # Check if HAProxy is running or not.
       track_script {
           chk_haproxy
       }
       notify_master /usr/bin/reroute_global
   }
   ```
6. As said above, I am running Debian 7. As can be seen in keepalived settings, I have a notify_master script. Here's everything needed to get the script running:

   ```
   apt-get install cpanminus libssl-dev build-essential libxml2-dev libexpat1-dev
   cpanm SOAP::Lite XML::Hash::LX IO::Interface
   git clone https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-api-perl-client.git
   mv softlayer-api-perl-client/SoftLayer /usr/share/perl5
   ```
7. Now that all the dependencies are in place, the script should work. Here's the script, which I saved as `/usr/bin/reroute_global`:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env perl
   use strict;
   use warnings;

   use SoftLayer::API::SOAP;
   use IO::Interface::Simple;

   # SoftLayer API Information
   my $api_user = 'YOUR_API_USERNAME';
   my $api_key  = 'YOUR_API_KEY';

   # Get the IP address associated with eth1
   my $if   = IO::Interface::Simple->new('eth1');

   # Create client object to SoftLayer_Account
   my $client = SoftLayer::API::SOAP->new('SoftLayer_Account', undef, $api_user, $api_key);

   # Get global IP address ID of first global IP address.
   my $global_ip_id = $client->getGlobalIpRecords()->result->[0]->{id};

   # Create client object to SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress_Global
   $client = SoftLayer::API::SOAP->new('SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress_Global', $global_ip_id, $api_user, $api_key);

   # Reroute global IP address to this systems public IP
   $client->route($if->address);
   ```

You'd need to change API_USERNAME/KEY to  match your API credentials. The script grabs the first global IP from your SoftLayer global IP addresses, and then reroutes the global IP to the system. In the case of a failover, the BACKUP becomes MASTER and runs the script, which routes the global IP address to itself.

### Testing

1. `curl http://<global_IP>`
2. On master server, `service haproxy stop`
3. On backup: `tail -f /var/log/syslog`. You should see something like this:

   ```
   Feb 12 01:11:55 proxy2-west Keepalived_vrrp[11816]: VRRP_Script(chk_haproxy) succeeded
   Feb 12 01:11:55 proxy2-west Keepalived_vrrp[11816]: SMTP alert successfully sent.
   Feb 12 01:12:29 proxy2-west Keepalived_vrrp[11816]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) forcing a new MASTER election
   Feb 12 01:12:29 proxy2-west Keepalived_vrrp[11816]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) forcing a new MASTER election
   Feb 12 01:12:30 proxy2-west Keepalived_vrrp[11816]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Transition to MASTER STATE
   Feb 12 01:12:31 proxy2-west Keepalived_vrrp[11816]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Entering MASTER STATE
   Feb 12 01:12:31 proxy2-west Keepalived_vrrp[11816]: Opening script file /usr/bin/reroute_global
   ```
4. `curl http://<global_IP>` (it should work if failover worked)